# Do I need to remove targets from UIButton before I release it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uibutton

Pretty much says it all... I've added a couple of targets to my UIButton, I just need to know if I need to remove them before the UIButton is released (and dealloc'd), or is it okay just to assume it'll tidy itself up?

Thanks!

EDIT: The scenario is this: A `UIViewController` which creates a button and has targets set as `self`:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

So now the button is being owned by the superview, and autoreleased at the end of the run loop. So, if I later remove the button from the view, will it dealloc okay, or do I also need to do `removeTarget:action:forControlEvents:` in order for the button to go away? I'm guessing the former, since I hope targets are assigned and not retained, but it'd be nice for someone to confirm it please? :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this? I'm almost positive you don't have to remove targets because nobody ever does, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I marked the answer as correct, because in the end @smparkes said that targets are not retained. And he must be right, otherwise I'd be seeing leaks all over my code. :)

Comment: @jowie: Leaks does not detect all leaks. Last I checked, by default it doesn't notice if you leak a UIViewController (because they're registered with NSNotificationCenter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you have other objects which are using the UIButton as a target?

If so - if those objects were implemented correctly - they should have their member variable getter/setter property set to "retain" - which means they should *hold a reference* to your UIButton.

Therefore, you can release your UIButton, but if the referencing objects still reference it - *they* will retain the UIButton.

That's of course if I'm understating your question correctly...

Comment: My point was I'd be shocked to believe that the targets were assigned, and not retained.

Comment: me too... So is it true that is not the case?

Comment: targets are not retained, at least not in general. If they were, you'd often get reference count loops and memory leaks.

Comment: Target of UIButton or UIBarButtonItem is not retained

Answer (score -2):

You have to remove the targets and cleanup your self.

Assume that you have an object O that has a button B and that V adds itself as target of B.
Assume also that O exposes B somehow and that there is someone else retaining B.
When you release O, B will still be alive and will point to O. Triggering any action on B will cause a crash.

Surely my example is contrived but it is better to be safer than sorry.